# Kubernetes RBAC: can't get cronjob even though user seems to have the needed permissons

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, rbac

Greetings fellow tinkerers !

**What is my issue ?**

In a nutshell, user *toto* can't "get" a cronjob, even though the permissions seem fine.
More precisely:

```
$> kubectl get cronjob/test -n my_namespace
Error from server (Forbidden): cronjobs.batch "test" is forbidden: User "toto" cannot get resource "cronjobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "my_namespace"
$> kubectl auth can-i get cronjob/test -n my_namespace
no
```

even tough:

```
$> kubectl auth can-i get cronjobs -n my_namespace
yes
$> kubectl auth can-i --list -n my_namespace
Resources      Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names   Verbs
...
cronjobs.batch []                 []               [get list watch list watch get]
...
$> kubectl get cronjobs -n my_namespace
NAME     SCHEDULE     ...   AGE
test     */5 * * * *        2d21h
```

Please also note that the command works fine when executed by an admin-level user (from group system:masters), or if I add *toto* to the group system:masters.

**What have I tried ?**

I added full-permissions to all resources in all namespaces, to a group *toto* belongs to (let's call it *my_group*). The fact that it didn't work even then makes me think that my issue might not be caused by permissions but by another k8s mechanism.

**Additional informations**

As requested here are some additional informations:

```
$> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T23:41:55Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14+", GitVersion:"v1.14.9-eks-c0eccc", GitCommit:"c0eccca51d7500bb03b2f163dd8d534ffeb2f7a2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-22T23:14:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

The cluster is hosted on AWS using the EKS service, therefore:

- contexts have users dynamically authenticated using the `aws-iam-authenticator` binary
- as the EKS doc mentions, we add users to groups in the `aws-auth` ConfigMap
- then we define some clusterroles + rolebindings, targeting those aforementioned groups.

Which for those 2 latter points, translates to the following yaml files:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  ...
  mapUsers: |
    ...
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/toto
      username: toto
      groups:
        - system:basic-user
        - my_group
    ...
```

```
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my_role
rules:
  ...
  - apiGroups: ["batch"]
    resources: ["cronjobs"]
    resourceNames: [""]
    verbs: ["list", "watch", "get"]
  ...
```

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my_rolebinding
  namespace: my_namespace
subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: my_group
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: my_role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: can you show RBAC permissions? `Role` and `RoleBinding`?

Comment: Yes, original message updated . :)

Comment: are you using `ClusterRole` object with `RoleBinding`?

Comment: Indeed, in order to have a cluster-defined role bound to a specific namespace :)
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding

Comment: I just reproduced your issue, and indeed it is strange. Will try later on. It bugs me.

Comment: yes, but you would use `Role` with `RoleBinding` for a specific namespace. Have you figured out what was the issue?

Comment: From my understanding of things, I don't think the choice of Role vs ClusterRole matters a lot here. The ClusterRole allows me to define it only once, and then use it as many times as wanted in namespaces through RoleBindings. Nope I haven't made anymore progress. I'm onto other things at the moment, hoping this post will get me the answer I need ^-^

Comment: ok. never heard of using `ClusterRole` with `RoleBinding`. I will play around a little bit more, and if I can't figure out what is what, I am going to open up an issue with k8s team. I really want to know what is wrong there.

Comment: Just had the same Problem and found out I was using a ServiceAccount which was bound to a different Role than I expected. So I edited Role XY but was using Role YX. 
Using ClusterRole and RoleBinding doesnt make sense. As long as you stay in the same Namespace you wont need a ClusterRole for CronJobs

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, the API group is `batch` and resource is `cronjobs` not `cronjobs.batch`.

Kubernetes [cluster-roles.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac/bootstrappolicy/testdata/cluster-roles.yaml) and docs for Kubernetes API [cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch).

`yaml` role should look like the following:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: my_namespace
  name: toto
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "batch"]
  resources: ["cronjobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "list", "watch"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D Although you are right and batch is the API group cronjobs belong to, resources are displayed as such when you list your permissions (`resource_name.api_group`).

Moreover as I mentioned, I tried to give my user (a group it is bound to, to be perfectly exact) full rights on every resource within every namespace, which even then still did not work.

Comment: Provide more details about your cluster, versions to be exact.
Where are you running the k8s? Can you provide `yaml` files so I can try to recreate it?
You can also try adding new user or removing toto and creating it again, also make sure user and roles are fully deleted.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So got it. The issue is the parameter `resourceNames`. When you specify this parameter, you need to also specify what specific resource name you mean.

**Example:**

If you create this`Role`...

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my_role
  namespace: toto
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "batch"]
    resources: ["cronjobs"]
    resourceNames: [""]
    verbs: ["list", "watch", "get"]
```

...and get cronjobs, you will get them, but you won't get a specific `cronJob` by name.

```
# kubectl -n toto --context toto-context get cronjobs
NAME          SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
cronjob-pod   */1 * * * *   False     0        4d21h           4d21h
# kubectl -n toto --context toto-context get cronjob cronjob-pod
Error from server (Forbidden): cronjobs.batch "cronjob-pod" is forbidden: User "toto" cannot get resource "cronjobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "toto"
```

But if you remove the parameter `resourceNames`, or write the resource name you want to get, it will work. So the following `Role` would work:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my_role
  namespace: toto
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "batch"]
    resources: ["cronjobs"]
    verbs: ["list", "watch", "get"]

# kubectl -n toto --context toto-context get cronjob cronjob-pod
NAME          SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
cronjob-pod   */1 * * * *   False     0        4d21h           4d21h
```

Also, in my case, this one would work:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my_role
  namespace: toto
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "batch"]
    resources: ["cronjobs"]
    resourceNames: ["cronjob-pod"]          <- specify the resource name
    verbs: ["list", "watch", "get"]
```

Note: `resourceNames: ["*"]` won't work.